# empty content in XML

Tags: xml

I just have a basic question with xml. I want to know whether it is valid to have an empty text content field ?

e.g

```
<Document></Document>
```

Thank you !

Comment: To be pedantic, there is a semantic difference between "valid" and "well-formed". "Well-formed" simply means that the structure is correct (which this is), while "valid" means that it conforms to whatever schema (or dtd) you have assigned to it. If this is a "text content field", you may have to look at the definition to see if zero length text is permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is, in XML, if your xml has XMLSchema (or any other schema), it depends on the schema

Comment: Thanks, I just had a quick doubt. As soon as the 12 minutes ends, I will accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in XML itself prevents you having an empty element (otherwise the `<img>` and `<br>` would break XHTML).

A specific XML application might require that an element has content though. You haven't stated where `<Document>` comes from, so we can't say for this particular case.

Comment: ah I c.... So <Document> alone would also work. But i want to provide a generalized interface. In some cases "text content" will be filled and in some cases it will be left blank. I just want to know whether leaving it blank is a valid case.

Comment: No. `<Document>` is a start tag. You must explicitly end every element in XML, but `<Document />` and `<Document></Document>` express the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

That XML is ok.

You can use http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp to test xml format.

Comment: @Kevin Reid: So... you don't like W3Schools, and for that reason alone you downvote my answer, witch is perfectly valid and answers the question presented, without even checking if the validator I indicate is correct. Nice, you should proud of yourself :)

Comment: Linking to any part of W3Schools may lead others to assume it is a useful resource in other areas — the link has connotations beyond pointing to the validator. And it's not that “I dislike W3Schools”, it's that I have been (correctly, as far as I have examined the matter) *warned away from them* by many other sources. (And if others disagree, they will upvote.)

Comment: The articles and examples that W3Schools have are not bad by themselves... it's just that they give the impression that what they have is complete. That nobody needs anything else than their tutorials. Other than that, they're OK, as long as you're not fooled into thinking that they have any official status.

Comment: @Mr Lister: With that i can agree :)